# How to make a category disapear if there are no elements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Ok guys, I have to make a list of items, they have a category. I'm Listing by Categories, however I don't want to show the category title unless there are items that belong there. I'm having trouble doing it.

```
<% @categorias.each do |categoria| %>
  <h3> <%= categoria.categoria_pt %></h3>
  <% @pratos_precos.each do |pratos_preco| %>
    <% if @pratos.find(pratos_preco.prato_id).categoria_pratos_id.to_s == categoria.id.to_s %>
```

i want something like this:

if there is a `prato_preco` who's `prato_id` matches a `prato_id` who's `categoria_pratos_id` matches `categoria_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it :)

```
     <% @pratocategorias = @pratos.where("categoria_pratos_id = ?", categoria.id) %>
     <% @pratocategorias.each do |pratocategoria|%>

     <% @pratosprecos = @pratos_precos.where("prato_id = ?", pratocategoria.id) %>
```